# RISC-V 64gc LD Truncated Relocation: R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20

Tags: ld, riscv, bare-metal

I can not get ld to link a very simple program because of a truncated relocation.

```
(init+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20 against symbol `globalPointer' defined in .bss section in out/bootloader.elf
```

An example assembly file that creates this issue:

```
.section init

.global start
.type start, @function
start:
    la gp, globalPointer

.end
```

with the following linker script:

```
ENTRY(start);
 
. = 0x80000000;
 
SECTIONS {
    .text : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(.init);
        *(.text);
    }
    .bss : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(.bss);
        PROVIDE(globalPointer = .);
    }
    .rodata : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(.rodata);
    }
    .data : ALIGN(4K) {
        *(.data);
    }
}
```

Assembled and linked with the following commands:

```
riscv64-elf-as -march=rv64gc source/entry.s -o build/entry.o
riscv64-elf-ld -nostdlib -melf64lriscv -T linker.ld build/entry.o -o out/bootloader.elf
```

With a toolchain made of up the following tools with `--target=riscv64-elf` as a configuration parameter and following the other flags [here at OsDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).

```
binutils: 2.37
gcc: 11.2.0
```

I have also tried [this prebuilt toolchain from kernel.org](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/tools/crosstool/files/bin/x86_64/11.1.0/x86_64-gcc-11.1.0-nolibc-riscv64-linux.tar.gz).

I was also able to trigger the same error in a C file with the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern volatile uint64_t* globalPointer;

int kernalMain(void){
    *globalPointer = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

So my issue is not isolated to assembly code.

Comment: Just tried another precompiled toolchain, same problem. The error goes away with PIC/PIE but then I can't link it because ld says that it isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my problem!

I missed a . in a symbol name.